# Issue with train.next_batch in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently facing an issue with the next_batch function. When I try to implement it with the code I have below, I get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nextBatch'
```

I am suspecting that the issue is stemming from the next_batch function. I have tried to create my own implementation of the function from the tensorflow example. I have based my code for this Logistic Regression model on the example below.

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.py

I have based the code for the next_batch function on a previous StackOverflow post.

[how to implement tensorflow's next_batch for own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994583/how-to-implement-tensorflows-next-batch-for-own-data#)

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import os as os

from LogRegModel import csvToTrainTF, csvtoTestTF

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename1 = dir_path + "/TrainData2.csv" 
filename2 = dir_path + "/TestData2.csv"

filenameTrain = 'TrainData2.tfrecords'
filenameTest = 'TestData2.tfrecords'

trainData = csvToTrainTF(filename1, filenameTrain)
testData = csvtoTestTF(filename2, filenameTest)

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 20
batch_size = 32
display_step = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 9])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([9,2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices = 1))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    start = 0

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(992/batch_size)

        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = trainData.nextBatch(batch_size) # Error is occurring in the train.next_batch call? Could you please tell me how to write out the function?            
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

            avg_cost += c/total_batch

            if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
                print("Epoch:", '%40d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    print("Optimization Finished")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    #I am not sure if this is the correct way to print out the accuracy. Could you please check this?
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: trainData[0:9], y: trainData[10]}))
```

Above is the code for the main function
Below is code for next_batch

```
def next_batch(self,batch_size,shuffle = True):
    start = self._index_in_epoch
    if start == 0 and self._epochs_completed == 0:
        idx = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)  # get all possible indexes
        np.random.shuffle(idx)  # shuffle indexe
        self._data = self.data[idx]  # get list of `num` random samples

    # go to the next batch
    if start + batch_size > self._num_examples:
        self._epochs_completed += 1
        rest_num_examples = self._num_examples - start
        data_rest_part = self.data[start:self._num_examples]
        idx0 = np.arange(0, self._num_examples)  # get all possible indexes
        np.random.shuffle(idx0)  # shuffle indexes
        self._data = self.data[idx0]  # get list of `num` random samples

        start = 0
        self._index_in_epoch = batch_size - rest_num_examples #avoid the case where the #sample != integar times of batch_size
        end =  self._index_in_epoch  
        data_new_part =  self._data[start:end]  
        return np.concatenate((data_rest_part, data_new_part), axis=0)
    else:
        self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
        end = self._index_in_epoch
        return self._data[start:end]
```

Comment: Your function is `next_batch`, but in the code you call `nextBatch`??

Comment: I am still getting the same error after the change. Do you (or anyone else) have any other ideas?